# How to open savedialogbox in excel from .net windows form

Tags: .net

I have created an application in vb.net from this application i want to open excel file with excel's saveAs option. Is there any way i can do this?

thanx

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you can do this prior to Office 2007, but in 07 onwards there is an Application.GetSaveAsFilename() method which pops up a save as dialog.

Something like this might do what you want (in C#):

```
        var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        app.Visible = true;

        var book = app.Workbooks.Open(@"I:\ApplicationsUAT\PriceGrab\PriceCheck.xls");
        book.Names.Item("dt").RefersToRange.Value = DateTime.Today.ToOADate();
        app.CalculateFull();

        object fld = app.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:"Microsoft Office Excel Workbook (*.xls), *.xls");
        if (fld is string)
            book.SaveAs((string)fld, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel12);
        book.Close(false);

        app.Quit();
```